# Параметры настроек конфигурации сервера БД

Tags: sql, oracle

Файл **init.ora** (oracle\product\11.2.0\server\config\scripts\init.ora) содержит несколько настроек сервера.

При вызове команды:

```
SELECT a.name, a.value  FROM v$parameter a
ORDER BY a.name
```

Идет вывод очень многих параметров (343 строки), которых нету в файла init.ora.
Я так полагаю, есть локальные настройки. Откуда они берутся?

Answer (score 2):

Файл **init.ora** не содержит настроек сервера. Этот файл содержит только пример значений параметров, о чём прямо в нём и сказано:

> NOTE: The values that are used in this file are **example values only**.

---

Параметры конфигурации сервера хранятся в *server parameter file* (SPFILE), который имеет бинарный формат. Имя по умолчанию: `spfile<SID>`. Где он находится, можно узнать так :

```
SQL> show parameter spfile
```

Обычно по пути `$ORACLE_HOME/dbs`. Изменения параметров с одновременным сохранением в   файл производятся командой:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET ... SCOPE=SPFILE
```

Подробнее см. главу [Initialization Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/initialization-parameters-2.html#GUID-FD266F6F-D047-4EBB-8D96-B51B1DCA2D61).

Answer (score 1):

Просмотреть значения параметров **init.ora** простым `SECECT .. FROM ..` не получится.
Сам файл init.ora по умолчанию хранится по пути *ORACLE_HOME\Database\INIT.ora*.
Или можно составить свой запрос, делая выборку из нескольких таблиц. Более подробно об этом можно почитать у [Тома Кайта](http://citforum.ru/database/oracle/kyte/02.shtml).

Comment: Извините, обманул. Можно попробовать выполнить запрос: SELECT t.* from V$PARAMETER t
where t.isdefault = 'FALSE'

Answer (score 1):

Естественно, в базе данных больше параметров. Просто те параметры, которые вы не указываете в файле init берут значения по умолчанию. Они то как раз и отображаются в представлении v$parameter (или v$paremeter2 или из sqlplus - команда show)
Для старта базы достаточно указать минимальный базовый список.